# Android MPChart | Align XAxis Labels with bars

Tags: android, kotlin, bar-chart

I'm having a problem with aligning xAxis labels with actual bars.
I'm using MPChart for Android.
Here's an image of how it looks like:
 [image]

As you can see, xAxis label is out of place. There should be one value under each group of bars.
I tried to fix it with
My code in Kotlin:

```
fun populateGraphData() {

        var barChartView = findViewById<BarChart>(R.id.chartConsumptionGraph)

        val barWidth: Float
        val barSpace: Float
        val groupSpace: Float

        barWidth = 0.45f
        barSpace = 0.1f
        groupSpace = 0.56f
        var titleobject = AvsF_response_year()
        var xAxisValues = ArrayList<String>()
        var yValueGroup1 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
        var yValueGroup2 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
        var barDataSet1: BarDataSet
        var barDataSet2: BarDataSet
        var i=1
        for(value in avsfDateResponseList){
            xAxisValues.add(value.dateTimeUTC)
            yValueGroup1.add(BarEntry(i.toFloat(),value.dayAheadTotalLoadForecastValue.toFloat()))
            yValueGroup2.add(BarEntry(i.toFloat(),value.actualTotalLoadValue.toFloat()))
            i=i+1
        }

        barDataSet1 = BarDataSet(yValueGroup1, "")
        barDataSet1.setColors(Color.CYAN, Color.CYAN)
        barDataSet1.label = "DAY AHEAD TOTAL LOAD FORECAST"
        barDataSet1.setDrawIcons(false)
        barDataSet1.setDrawValues(false)

        barDataSet2 = BarDataSet(yValueGroup2, "")
        barDataSet2.label = "ACTUAL TOTAL LOAD"
        barDataSet2.setColors(Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE)
        barDataSet2.setDrawIcons(false)
        barDataSet2.setDrawValues(false)

        var barData = BarData(barDataSet1, barDataSet2)
        barChartView.description.text = "entso-e"
        barChartView.description.isEnabled = true
        barChartView.description.textSize = 3f
        barData.setValueFormatter(LargeValueFormatter())
        barChartView.setData(barData)
        barChartView.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth)
        barChartView.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0f)
        val size = avsfDateResponseList.size.toFloat() +avsfDateResponseList.size.toFloat()
        barChartView.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(size)
        barChartView.groupBars(0f, groupSpace, barSpace)
        barChartView.setFitBars(true)
        barChartView.getData().setHighlightEnabled(true)

        var legend = barChartView.legend
        legend.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM)
        legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT)
        legend.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL)
        legend.setDrawInside(false)

        var legenedEntries = arrayListOf<LegendEntry>()
        legenedEntries.add(LegendEntry("DAY AHEAD TOTAL LOAD FORECAST", Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE, 8f, 8f, null, Color.CYAN))
        legenedEntries.add(LegendEntry("ACTUAL TOTAL LOAD", Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE, 8f, 8f, null, Color.BLUE))
        legend.setCustom(legenedEntries)

        legend.setYOffset(2f)
        legend.setXOffset(2f)
        legend.setYEntrySpace(0f)
        legend.setTextSize(9f)

        val xAxis = barChartView.getXAxis()
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f)
        xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true)
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
        xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 60F
        xAxis.textSize = 10f

        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM)
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisValues))
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
        xAxis.setLabelCount(avsfDateResponseList.size.toInt())
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
        xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true)
        barChartView.setDragEnabled(true)

        barChartView.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false)
        barChartView.setScaleEnabled(true)

        val leftAxis = barChartView.getAxisLeft()
        leftAxis.setValueFormatter(LargeValueFormatter())
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
        leftAxis.setSpaceTop(1f)
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f)

        barChartView.data = barData
        barChartView.setVisibleXRange(1f, 18f)
    }
```

I've tried deleting and adding each one of these lines and nothing seems to be working right.
Can someone help me?

Comment: xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 90F  xAxis.textSize = 8f . Do you try this. Probably won't fit.